# Connect columns in SharePoint/relating columns from 2 lists on Power Apps/SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

So I have 2 SharePoint lists in the same site. They have records with IDs which coincide to record names. Both lists have a common column, the record ID, which is connected but I'm not sure how.

Only one of them have the record names column, how can I connect it?

I'm using the list which doesn't have the name but I want it to appear even at least as a text on Power apps by relating it to its ID.

Either by sharepoint or on power apps (like if ID from one list is equal to the ID in the other, then the text should display the project name from the other list).

How can I do this?

Comment: Set `Text` property of label control in this format: `Lookup(List2DataSource, RecordID = IDValueFromList1).ProjectName`. Use list and column names as per your SharePoint site.

Comment: If this is a lookup column, you can edit the column (on the list with the reference) and choose additional columns to display in the list by checking the box next to the one you want. That'll take care of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Text field and then apply the following formula to the control that reading a data from **List1** :

```
LookUp(List2, RecordID = ThisItem.RecordID).ProjectName
```

That's it !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show the project name column value from List 2 inside form/gallery showing item(s) from List 1,

Set `Text` property of label control in this format:

```
Lookup(List2DataSource, RecordID = IDValueFromList1).ProjectName
```

Use list and column names as per your SharePoint site.

**For Example**:

```
LookUp(List2, RecordID = ThisItem.ID).ProjectName
```